# How to implement runnable with java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am trying to create a program that will carry on running automatically without me having to do anything. I am a bit confused on how to implement runnable in java so I can create a thread that will go to sleep for a certain period of time and then run the re-run the program after the sleep period is over.

```
public class work {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    work test = new work();
    test.information();

}

private ConfigurationBuilder OAuthBuilder() {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("dy1Vcv3iGYTqFif6m4oYpGBhq");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("wKKJ1XOPZbxX0hywDycDcZf40qxfHvkDXYdINWYXGUH04qU0ha");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("4850486261-49Eqv5mogjooJr8lm86hB20QRUpxeHq5iIzBLks");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("QLeIKTTxJOwpSX4zEasREtGcXcqr0mY8wk5hRZKYrH5pd");
    return cb; 



}

public void information() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = OAuthBuilder();
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    try {
        User user = twitter.showUser("ec12327");
        Query query = new Query("gym fanatic");
        query.setCount(100);
        query.lang("en");
        String rawJSON =null ;
        String statusfile = null;
        int i=0;

    try {     

                QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                for(int z = 0;z<5;z++){
                for( Status status : result.getTweets()){

                    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());

                       rawJSON = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
                         statusfile = "results" + z +".txt";
                        storeJSON(rawJSON, statusfile);

                        i++;

                }
    }


                System.out.println(i);

              }   
              catch(TwitterException e) {         
                System.out.println("Get timeline: " + e + " Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
                if(e.getErrorCode() == 88){
                    Thread.sleep(900);
                    information();

                }
              }     


    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode() == 88) {
            System.err.println("Rate Limit exceeded!!!!!!");
            Thread.sleep(90);
            information();
            try {
                long time = e.getRateLimitStatus().getSecondsUntilReset();
                if (time > 0)
                    Thread.sleep(900000);
                    information();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

 private static void storeJSON(String rawJSON, String fileName) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try
        {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            fileWriter.write(rawJSON);
            fileWriter.write("\n");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(fileWriter!=null) {
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have severable options to implement a thread in Java.

### Implementing `Runnable`

When a class implements the `Runnable` interface, he has to override the `run()` method. This runnable can be passed to the constructor of a `Thread`. This thread can then be executed using the `start()` method. If you'd like to have this thread run forever and sleep, you could do something like the following:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }
}
```

### Extending `Thread`

Thread itself also has a `run()` method. When extending thread, you can override the Thread's `run()` method and provide your own implementation. Then you'd have to instantiate your own custom thread, and start it in the same way. Again, like the previous you could do this:

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }
}
```

Source: [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: How would i implement it with the initial code, i'm a bit confused how it works

Comment: @shah Well what's the code that you'd like to see running continuously? If you have logic that needs to run continuously, create a class, implement the `Runnable` interface and define your logic in the `run()` method. Afterwards, create a thread and pass in your class that implements the interface. Then call `start()` on the thread.

Comment: I want to be able to run to run the for loop to get it to keep printing results and then stop for x amount of seconds and then for it to run the for loop again to print more results.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer, you need to either extend Thread or implement Runnable on your Work class. Extending Thread is probably easier.

```
public class work extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        // your app will run forever, consider a break mechanism
        while(true) {
            // sleep for a while, otherwise you'll max your CPU
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            this.information();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,    InterruptedException {
        work test = new work();
        test.start();
   }

    // ... rest of your class
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable); // create new thread instance
    thread.start(); // start thread
}


public static Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){

      final int DELAY = 500;
      while(true){
          try{
               // Code goes here;
               Thread.sleep(DELAY)
          } catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();                    
          }

      }

   }
```

}